# Script to Install Font in Windows XP

Tags: vbscript, windows-xp

I am trying to install fonts in windows XP using a VBScript. But for some reason my script works fine in Windows 7 but does not work in Windows XP. I need to install fonts without a system reboot so, I had to choose this approach instead of other registry change approaches which would need a system reboot. Here is my VBScript

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace("D:\Logs\")
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("Roboto-Italic.ttf")
objFolderItem.InvokeVerb("Install")
```

My guess is the InvokeVerb("Install") command is not working in Windows XP. In that case are there any alternatives? Please guide me Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next script (a code snippet) should work on (obsolete) Windows XP:

```
Const ssfFONTS = &H14&

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(ssfFONTS)
objFolder.CopyHere "D:\Logs\Roboto-Italic.ttf"
```

If the font is already installed then you could be prompted to overwrite it. Not sure whether or not reboot required using above approach...

See [ShellSpecialFolderConstants enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774096(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Specifies unique, system-independent values that identify special
>   folders. These folders are frequently used by applications but which
>   may not have the same name or location on any given system.

Among others:

> - `ssfFONTS 0x14 (20)`. Virtual folder that contains installed fonts. A
>     typical path is `C:\Windows\Fonts`.

Read [Hey, Scripting Guy! How Can I Install Fonts Using a Script?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/04/25/how-can-i-install-fonts-using-a-script.aspx):

> As soon as the font has been added to the folder, the operating system
>   will immediately install the font for you...
>   That’s true, but with one very important *caveat*: you must copy the
>   file using the *`Shell` object*. Admittedly, you can use `WMI` or the
>   `FileSystemObject` to copy a file into the `Fonts` folder; however,
>   when you do so the operating system will not automatically install the
>   font for you. As far as we know, the only programmatic way to get
>   Windows to recognize that a new font has been added to the `Fonts`
>   folder, and thus get Windows to install that font for you, is to use
>   the *`Shell` object*.

Comment: Thanks JosefZ, I already tried, the snippet you provided copies the font to C:\Windows\Fonts location but does not install it.

Comment: Thank you JosefZ, I tried it again with your script it worked. Dont know what went wrong last time. Thank you for your explanation too.

Comment: Hi JosefZ, The script you provided me is again not working. I copied and pasted the same thing. It is able to copy to the C:\Windows\Fonts folder but does not get installed. Is there anything in OS which is blocking?

Comment: @marak There is no reason to distrust the code snippet and explanation provided by the _Hey, Scripting Guy!_ site. Not much more to say about, sorry.

Comment: JosefZ, I was able to figure it out. The script was able to install the font, but it was not getting enumerated in the Internet explorer until the control panel fonts folder was opened. So, I added a script which would automatically open the controlPanel fonts folder after installing the font